# Return "old-style" browser-tabs in Chrome Canary 71.0.3558.0 (Windows 2012 R2 x64)

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs

I found few pages with chrome://flags keys, something like this:
https://www.ghacks.net/2018/09/05/how-to-restore-the-old-google-chrome-design/

but my Chrome still show new ugly tabs. As I understand these flags are deprecated How do You set old tabs UI in 2018?..

I also tried " --old-new-tab-page" key in shortcut, no result too

Comment: [Chrome Bug: "Several flags that made the new disgusting UI go away in favor of the old one are now gone in v71"](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=912416)

Comment: I don't have "Normal" in v.71 (for chrome://flags/#top-chrome-md)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go here: chrome://flags/#top-chrome-md and set that setting to either "Normal" or "Hybrid".

Comment: Hmmmm. Does not work for Canary, but worked for standard Chrome.. Thank You, I'll mark it as answeer!

Comment: Doesn't work with Chrome 71

Answer (score 4):

You can't, 71 forces the new tab look and the only way around it is to use the offline installer for version 69. Then use the flags to change to normal. Of course you will want to turn off chrome updates to keep 69 from updating.

Comment: Thank You for useful comment, @Painless!

Answer (score 0):

If you type chrome://flags and do a search there for "new tab page" there are a couple of options at the bottom, however, I admit that I do not know the difference between the two.  In either case, either one of these will give you back the rectangular tabs with the page screenshots in them: "New Tab Page Material Design Icons" or "New Tab Page Material Design UI"

Comment: Hi Gina! I tried, but no result. Tried to set bot to "Enabled" and "Disabled"..